# How to query Range

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml

Right now my code is is Equals in the query how can i prevent for example that if i book 2014-12-01 01:00 to 2014-12-02 01:00 This is a hole day, that no one else can for example book the same time but between any  time and that range?

My code looks like this right now.

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'EventDate\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>'
        + fromTime.toISOString() + '</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'EndDate\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + toTime.toISOString() +
        '</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>');


    this.collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(collListItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing missing opening tag `<Where>`.Your code must be

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'EventDate\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>'
    + fromTime.toISOString() + '</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'EndDate\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + toTime.toISOString() +
    '</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>');


this.collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(collListItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Geq` and `Leq` to formulate the range query as below

```
query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'EventDate\'/>' + 
    '<Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + fromTime.toISOString() + '</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name=\'EndDate\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + toTime.toISOString() + '</Value></Leq></And></Where></Query></View>');
```